# PHP: user declared variable overwrites variable in $GLOBALS

Tags: php, variables

I declared a variable ($bonus) in my code and assigned a value to it.  After this, `$GLOBALS['bonus']` contains the same value.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Have you enabled register globals?

Comment: `$bonus` (in the global scope) and `$GLOBALS['bonus']` are the same... that's expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the way $GLOBALS works in PHP http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.globals.php

Answer (score 0):

That's the way how it should behave.

```
<?php
function test() {
    $foo = "local variable";

    echo '$foo in global scope: ' . $GLOBALS["foo"] . "\n";
    echo '$foo in current scope: ' . $foo . "\n";
}

$foo = "Example content";
test();
?>
```

> $foo in global scope: Example content 
> $foo in current scope: local
>   variable

***[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)***

Answer (score 0):

If there's a global variable of the same name, it gets overwritten, that's normal behaviour in PHP.

And this is also why you should never ever EVER use globals.